# Linking to items in CGridView/CListView with pagination

Tags: yii

I would like to be able to link to items listed by CGridView or CListView (or any view with pagination), for example:

`CHtml::link('Link to item #123', array('/item/index', 'item_id'=>123));`

The goal is to have CGridView/CListView open up on the page where item with ID 123 is!

Can this be achieved in a reasonably trivial way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be, here is an example of how you would do it:
**Example**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'customer-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'selectionChanged'=>'js:function(id){
 n = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);
 if (n>0){
    $.ajax({
            url: "'.Yii::app()->urlManager->createUrl('customer/view/').'",
            type: "GET",
            data: {"id": parseInt(n)},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
            $("#customer-div").html(data);
         }
         });',

    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    array(
                'name'  => 'trading_name',
                'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->trading_name, Yii::app()
                 ->createUrl("customer/view/",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey)))',
                 'type'  => 'raw',
                 'options' => array('ajax' => array('type' => 'get', 'url'=>'js:$(this).attr("href")',
                 'success' => 'js:function(data) { 
                  $("#tab1").html(data);')
                  ),
             ),
    'email',    
    'site_code',

    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
```